# Lacunary series - Finding a limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, lacunary-series

Let, $f$ be the function defined on the open unit disk:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty} x^{n^2}
\end{equation*}

The aim of the exercise is to find the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $-1$.
I tried considering the function $g$ defined by $g(x)=f(-x)$ and separating the positive and then negative terms... but I am not making any progress.

Does anyone have an idea?

I don't know if this is useful but I have proved that :

\begin{equation*}
f(x) \sim \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{1-x}} \quad \text{as $x$ approaches $1$}
\end{equation*}

Comment: The limit in $-1^{+}$!

Comment: I know this is why I said that it may not be useful...

Comment: Mathematica rewrites the sum in terms of an elliptic theta function, as $\frac12\left(1+\vartheta_3(0,x)\right)$. The graph of this function very much appears to have limit zero as $x\to-1^+$.

Comment: Sorry, the graph shows limit $\frac12$, not zero. Once again, Mathematica’s default placement of axes tripped me up. Mark’s answer looks good (save for the missing sum, which will likey be fixed quickly).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another approach is by considering $f(t) = e^{i\pi t-\alpha t^2}$ then,

$\displaystyle \hat{f}(x) = 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{itx}f(t)\,dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{itx}e^{i\pi t-\alpha t^2}\,dt = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}e^{-\frac{(x+\pi)^2}{4\alpha}}$ so that using Poisson Summation formula we have, $$\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}e^{-\alpha n^2} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{(2n+1)^2\pi^2}{4\alpha}}$$

i.e., $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}e^{-\alpha n^2} = \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{(2n+1)^2\pi^2}{4\alpha}}$ and letting $\alpha \to 0^{+}$ gives the desired limit to be equal to $\dfrac{1}{2}$ (since, $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{(2n+1)^2\pi^2}{4\alpha}} < \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{n\pi^2}{4\alpha}} = \frac{e^{-\frac{\pi^2}{4\alpha}}}{1-e^{-\frac{\pi^2}{4\alpha}}}$).

**Addendum:** It also follows from one of the [Jacobi Triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product) identity: $$\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^nx^{n^2} = \prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} (1-x^{2k})(1-x^{2k-1})^2$$

Comment: I think you should replace the last equation of your answer by $$ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{(2n+1)^2\pi^2}{4\alpha}} < \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{n\pi^2}{4\alpha}} = \frac{e^{-\frac{\pi^2}{4\alpha}}}{1-e^{-\frac{\pi^2}{4\alpha}}}$$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks! Edited.

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution based on the theory of theta functions and I believe more elementary solutions are desirable.

---

Put $x=-q$ and then you want to know the limit of expression $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-q)^{n^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\vartheta_{4}(q)\right)$$ when $q\to 1^{-}$. Now we can exploit the link between theta functions and elliptic integrals and note that when $q\to 1^{-}$ then elliptic modulus $k\to 1^{-}$ and we have $$\vartheta_{4}(q) = \sqrt{\frac{2k'K}{\pi}}$$ We now interchange $k, k'$ and thus calculate the limit of $\sqrt{2kK'/\pi}$ as $k\to 0^{+}$. Noting that $$K'=\log\left(\frac{4}{k}\right)+o(1)$$ as $k\to 0^{+}$ (see [this blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/12/elementary-approach-to-modular-equations-ramanujan-theory-2.html) for a proof) we can see that the expression $\sqrt{2kK'/\pi}$ tends to $0$ as $k \to 0^{+}$. The desired limit is thus $1/2$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is yet another solution. After the change of variable $x = -y$ with $y \to 1^-$, we have

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} y^{4n^2}(1 - y^{4n+1}). \tag{1}$$

Now the idea is to identify $\text{(1)}$ as sort of Riemann sum for the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-2t} \, dt = \frac{1}{2}$.

To this end, we first fix arbitrary $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$ and choose $N = N(\epsilon, y) \in \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$ such that $y^{4N^2} \to \epsilon$ as $y \to 1^-$. For instance, choose $N$ to be any nearest integer to $(\log \epsilon / 4 \log y)^{1/2}$. Then using the alternating behavior of $\text{(1)}$ we find that

$$ \left| \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} y^{4n^2}(1 - y^{4n+1}) \right| \leq y^{4N^2} \xrightarrow[y \to 1^-]{} \epsilon $$

which will be shown to be negligible as $\epsilon \to 0^+$. Next, we define $t_n = t_n(y)$ by

$$t_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} (4k+1)(1-y) = (2n^2+3n+1)(1-y) $$

and $\Delta t_n = \Delta t_n (y) := t_n - t_{n-1}$. Then we have $y = 1 - \frac{t_n}{2n^2+3n+1}$. Now from the following simple inequality

$$ (4n+1)y^{4n+1}(1-y) \leq 1 - y^{4n+1} \leq (4n+1)(1-y), $$

we find that

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{n=0}^{N} \exp\left\{ 4(n+1)^2 \log\left( 1 - \frac{t_n}{2n^2+3n+1} \right) \right\} \Delta t_n \tag{2}\\
&\qquad \leq \sum_{n=0}^{N} y^{4n^2}(1 - y^{4n+1}) \\
&\qquad \leq \sum_{n=0}^{N} \exp\left\{ 4n^2 \log\left( 1 - \frac{t_n}{2n^2+3n+1} \right) \right\} \Delta t_n \tag{3}
\end{align*}

Since $t_N \to \frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and $\max_{0 \leq n \leq N} \Delta t_n = (4N+1)(1-y) \to 0$ as as $y \to 1^-$, we can think of bounds $\text{(2)}$ and $\text{(3)}$ as Riemann sums of $e^{-2t}$ over the inteval $[0, \frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1}{\epsilon}]$. Taking limit as $y \to 1^-$, it is not hard to show (but slightly annoying to give a full argument) that both bounds converge to the same value, which is

$$ \lim_{y \to 1^-} \sum_{n=0}^{N} y^{4n^2}(1 - y^{4n+1}) = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1}{\epsilon}} e^{-2t} \, dt = \frac{1 - \epsilon}{2}. $$

Then by the usual 3-epsilon argument, we have

$$ \limsup_{y \to 1^-} \left| f(-y) - \frac{1}{2} \right| \leq \frac{3 \epsilon}{2}
\xrightarrow[\epsilon \to 0^+]{} 0 $$

and hence the claim follows.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-x)^{n^2}= \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{(2k)^2} - \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{(2k+1)^2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left((x^4)^{k^2}  -(x^4)^{(k+\frac12)^2} \right)
$$
$$
\lim_{x\to 1^-} \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-x)^{n^2}= \lim_{y\to 1^-} \sum_{n=0}^\infty
\left(y^{k^2}  -y^{(k+\frac12)^2} \right)
$$
which you can show goes to $\frac12$.

(In fact, by the time $x = 0.9$ the sum is $\frac12 + \epsilon$ with $0<\epsilon < 10^{-6}$.)

Comment: @Semiclassical We have $|x|<1$, so it is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Is there a missing $\sum$ in the last equality?

Comment: Yes, there was. Fixed it

Comment: How do we prove that last sum tends to $1/2$? Do we have any estimates for it as $y\to 1^{-}$?

Comment: "which you can show goes to 1/2" This is not really an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had a near-obvious proof that $$\lim_{x\to 1^-} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( x^{k^2}-x^{(k+\rho)^2}\right) = \rho$$ for all $\rho>0$.  But my reasoning was flawed (although the statement is still true, I think).